# Strategy to staple something to a soffit from a distance

Tags: tools

I need to staple [mouse-trapping sticky pads/glue traps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012VJLZOM) to the soffits under the roof ridge of a house (roughly where the red arrow is pointing, under the overhang). (Reason: some bats have taken to entering the inside of the house from there. This is to trap the bats.)

The ladder doesn't quite reach high enough.

If anyone can suggest alternative strategies to somehow staple said sticky pads to the soffits near the roof ridge, please share.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered how you will get the dead bat down after it is stuck in the trap?

Comment: Are you allowed to interfere with bats? In many places they are protected and the consequences can be expensive or even a "special" holiday...

Comment: This is not a good plan, if it works you'll have bats starving to death up there for days, then you'll have dead bats stuck up there until you take them down. Plus it won't deter future bats or birds. You're far better off getting someone to fix the hole so they can't use it.

Comment: Bats are usually useful to have around, but not in the house.  Would look into building/buying bat houses to place around your land after blocking the hole into the house.

Comment: Good point @crip659, bats eat a lot of insects (thousands an hour apparently) which most consider pests. Give them a home and they'll help keep the mosquito population down.

Comment: @GdD  Yes, bats have a bad reputation but are beneficial as long as their not rabid. They still scare the piss out of me if I get one in my house, but that's my problem!

Comment: I keep mice away using ultrasonic sound generators, seems to work pretty well.  Doing some quick research, it would seem that they would work humanely against bats as well.

Comment: To answer the question as asked, "Buy, borrow or rent a longer ladder". However, the comments are _very_ applicable, and attempting to trap them on sticky mouse traps is probably not the right solution at all.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Please share the brand+model of any ultrasonic sound generators you've found effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I understand your frustration, but find a way to exclude the bats. Google "copper mesh for plugging holes to exclude rodents or bats".

And I don't think glue traps would be effective.

http://www.wildernex.com/services/bat-removal/

Comment: Agreed.  Killing bats is a really lousy approach.

Comment: I think any opening can be sealed. The problem is what about the bats that can't get out? For rats the pros attach a one way door or other route out.

Answer (score 2):

Bats do not create openings.  If there is an opening in the soffit then it was caused by something else and other animals can also enter.  What does the hole lead to inside the house -- the attic or a tall ceiling?  First close off the opening from the inside, then rent a tall ladder to close the soffit hole (at night, when the bats are outside).  Better yet, hire a professional to handle it; they can remove the bats in a humane manner.

Comment: My anti-rat effort wound up with at least one dead rat in the walls that stunk and then flies came - those big ones.  The pro used a method I would never have thought of.  I wish I had called the pro first but I had to try myself.  You can call the pro first.  You have a nice house so you can afford to do it right.